# GET Method goes through instead of POST when redirecting

Tags: javascript, post

I am getting the `GET` method through instead of the `POST`. It seems like when I redirect it, the `POST` is called instead of `GET`. Is there a way to redirect with the `POST` method going through?

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#show').click(function(){
    $('#output').html('sending..');
      var jobject = JSON.stringify(oject);
      console.log(jobject);
      $.ajax({
        method:'post',
        url:'storage.php',
        data:{json:oject},
        success : function(){
          window.location.href = "footer.php";
        }
      })
      .done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
  });
});
```

***SOLVED:***

All i did was add a form that has a hidden value

```
<form id = "postform" action = "cart.php" method = "post">
  <input type = "hidden" id="obj" name="obj" val="">
  <input type = "submit" value = "Show Cart" id = "showcart">
</form>
```

In the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#showcart").click(function(){
    var json = JSON.stringify(object)
    $('#obj').val(json);
    $('#obj').submit();
  });
});
```

Thank you for everyone (no one) that has answered but hope this helps.

Comment: this should POST to storage.php then GET footer.php ... are you seeing something different in your developer tools network tab? if `#show` is a **submit** button, then what you see may be something else entirely, depending on the `<form>` element (if this is indeed a submit button within a form of course)

Comment: @JaromandX  `#show` is not a submit button, its just a button that redirect to `footer.php`

Comment: when you click the button, what do you observe in the browsers Developer Tools network tab